# polyfills.js:1 [webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-dependency-injection, angular-devkit

If i edit something in the webpage at that time angular application goes into infinite page load process for some mini, can any one help me with this issue.

I was updating my angular project from 15 to 16 at that time i got this error while new revision under 16 project